# Store Application Data in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

We're going to be moving lots of computers round in the fairly near future, and I thought I'd get all prepared by migrating all my application connection strings into one central location, so that I can update them in one fell swoop when the time comes.

I thought: "I know, I'll store them in the Active Directory"

Unfortunately, my knowledge of Active Directory is so slim as to be almost negligible. I can read groups and detect which users are in those groups, and basic things like that, but I would not know how to go about structuring Active Directory to hold this information.

I thought it might be good to have a "ConnectionRespository" place, with lots of named "Connection" objects in it, but I have no ideas how to go about setting up such a thing. Ideally, I'd like an application (in C#) to manage it, adding and removing Connection objects as necessary.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Word of caution... If your connection strings include the ID/password you'll need to consider encrypting the values in AD.  Anyone with an LDAP tool and a small amount of knowledge would be able read those values and obtain access to your databases.

Comment: All of our connection strings (but one) use integrated security, and the one has a requirement that password is not stored by the application between launches.

Comment: In my case i might want to store things such as i)the url to a government xml data feed ii)the current exchange rate iii)the name of a server to connect to iv)the value a transaction must be before government mandated reporting is required.  i, *of course*, would never, *ever*, store a connection string in Active Directory - that would be simply too convenient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

serviceconnectionpoint objects are designed for this kind of thing. They are generic data objects that dont mean anything to Windows. No schema change needed

However its not clear to me that you need to put this stuff in AD. Connection string info logically belongs to the app servers; AD is for stuff that everybody needs

Answer (score 5):

The specific functionality you are looking for is an ["Active Directory Application Partition"](https://www.google.com/search?q=active%20directory%20application%20partition&gws_rd=ssl). There's a great [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigmcmurtry/) with a book's worth of information and [code samples](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430023727/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigmcmurtry/archive/2004/03/04/83832.aspx) as well.

I would discuss this with your Systems Architecture/Operations group before proceeding. You are going to have to modify your AD schema, and I know that process can take a long time at many organizations.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like something i don't actually want to use after all. If it requires changing anything, with the help of anyone, as well as blogfulls of code-samples, it's probably not a mature enough solution.

Comment: LDAP and AD are certainly "mature enough" technologies, but they are not highly abstracted with simple interfaces; you need to know how the data is organized in order to use it well. If you haven't worked with LDAP before, I certainly wouldn't recommend a project of extending Active Directory for custom data storage as your first project...

Answer (score 1):

Extending Active Directory means you quickly hit lots problems, as even rebooting your AD server will need the approval of lots of people in most companies.

I would just put all your sheared config data in a XML file that you download from a web server.

Or put the config info in the registry of every machine on your network with an Active Directory Group policy.